# DNS setup for snowflake privatelink

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create a private hosted zone
".privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com" in route53
Does it have to use this domain name ?Is it mandatory to have a domain created with "privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com" ?

Comment: read the documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink.html seems to imply that it mandatory as the optional parts are prior to that domain aka `<account>.<region_id>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com` so it the nature of the question related to you cannot setup that record, and thus want it to be something else, or are you having problems?

Comment: I would also reach out to Snowflake Support with this request.